# mongo $in php doesnt work

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to get the following mongo query work using PHP.

```
$users = array(26549,42852);

        $db_mon_con = $mon_con->main;
        $collection = $db_mon_con->main_a;


  $cursor = $collection->find(array('userid' => 
                                    array('$in' => $users)
                                  )
                                  );
```

One of the documents that should be returned looks like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5284ef9a47ee3f45c73546f8"),
"id" : "22523",
"invitations" : [{
  "employerid" : "1481",
  "jobid" : "6272",
  "createdon" : "2013-09-10 21:31:39",
  "updatedon" : "2013-09-16 08:59:13",
  "status" : "rejected",
  "remarks" : "no activity"
}],
"name" : "ss",
"profilecompletion" : 0,
"userid" : "26549"
}
```

Comment: can you add some sample data / records you expect to be returned by this query?

Comment: This should work. You have an error somewhere else.

Comment: Can you share your document schema ? I hope your key is same as userid and no typo..

Comment: But in your first question you mention that there is no type mismatch but it is quiet obvious that it not matching the type -1

Answer (score 1):

You *do* have a type mismatch: you are passing in integers to your query, but the `userid` stored in mongo are strings (`"userid" : "26549"` as opposed to `"userid" : 26549`).  You'll need to convert your integers to strings before you query using them:

```
$users = array("26549","42852");
```

Alternatively, you could make sure that wherever you're inserting the `userid`, you insert it as a proper integer.

Comment: I have edited the document strucuture. It now shows a simpler document. "userid" is not the child of profileviewers.

Comment: I've edited my answer — your problem remains a type mismatch, converting the `users` to strings should fix it.